# Prove that if $ \Gamma $ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \beta $ for every formula $\beta$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Considering that $\Gamma$ is inconsistent if $ \Gamma \vdash ¬(\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) $ for some formula $\alpha$.

How to prove that if $ \Gamma $ is inconsistent, then $ \Gamma \vdash \beta $?

Do I need to assume that a proof of  $ ¬(\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) $ exists and try to find $\beta$ using axioms? Is it possible?

List of axioms:

[Axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyt78.png)

Comment: You can even prove that Bertrand Russell is actually the Pope.

Comment: @Levent: Only of the vocabulary of the theory you're working in allows you to state that claim. (Though indeed I have never seen Bertrand Russell and the Pope in the same room at the same time, which -- now that you mention it -- is kind of suspect ...)

Comment: We need to know more about the system at hand in order to answer all of your questions.  What are the axiom(s) and the rule(s) of inference?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood, edited with the axioms. Thanks. I may use Deduction Theorem and Modus Ponens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can prove $\Gamma \vdash ¬(\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$, you can say $$\Gamma,\lnot \beta \vdash ¬(\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) \\ \Gamma \vdash (\lnot \beta \implies¬(\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)) \\ \Gamma \vdash \beta$$

Comment: How did you get from the second line to the last? Using axioms and Modus Ponens?

Comment: It is the usual proof by contradiction.  From something implies contradiction, derive not something.

Answer (score 0):

With Ax.1 and Ax.2 we can easily prove two useful results : the *Deduction Theorem* and:

> $\vdash (\alpha \to \alpha)$.

From the last one, we have:

> > $\Gamma, \lnot \beta \vdash (\alpha \to \alpha)$.

From $\Gamma, \vdash \lnot (\alpha \to \alpha)$ we have:

> > $\Gamma, \lnot \beta \vdash \lnot (\alpha \to \alpha)$.

Now we may "cook" the two results together with the *Ded Th* and Ax.3:

> $\vdash (\delta \to \gamma) \to ((\delta \to \lnot \gamma) \to \lnot \delta)$

to conclude with:

> > $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \lnot \beta$.

Using Ax.10 (*Double Negation*):

> $\vdash \lnot \lnot \beta \to \beta$,

we conclude with:

> > $\Gamma \vdash \beta$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Prove that, in Polish notation, $\vdash$CpCNpq.

More fully:

```
axiom 1 CpCqp
axiom 2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
axiom 3 CCpqCCpNqNp
axiom 4 CNNpp
2 r/p 5 CCpCqpCCpqCpp
5, 1  6 CCpqCpp
6 q/Cqp 7 CCpCqpCpp
7, 1    8 Cpp
hypothesis  9 | p
hypothesis  10 || Np
1 q/Nq      11 || CpCNqp
1 q/Nq p/Np 12 || CNpCNqNp
11, 9       13 || CNqp
12, 10      14 || CNqNp
3 p/Nq, q/p 15 || CCNqpCCNqNpNNq
15, 14      16 || CCNqNpNNq
16, 14      17 || NNq
4 p/q       18 || CNNqq
18, 17      19 || q
10-19       20 | CNpq
9-20        21 CpCNpq
21 p/Cpp    22 CCppCNCppq
22, 8       23 CNCppq
```

Thus, given that $\Gamma$ $\vdash$ NCpp for some formula p, since 23 holds, it follows that $\Gamma$ $\vdash$ q.